# Python, MetaClasses, HTTPException, __init_subclass__ - TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

Tags: python, class, httpexception

Could somebody point me to how to solve my problem:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

class HTTPExceptions(HTTPException):
    subclasses = dict()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.subclasses[f'{cls.__name__}'] = cls.__name__


class Error501(HTTPExceptions):
    code = 501
```

when i try to run:

```
raise HTTPExceptions.subclasses['Error501']
```

i got

```
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

any chance somebody knows how to solve it?

Comment: ``cls.__name__`` stores the name of the class. Use ``cls`` to store the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cls.__name__` is a string, so the way you have defined `HTTPExceptions.subclasses` is as a map of strings to strings. I assume what you intended is:

```
cls.subclasses[f'{cls.__name__}'] = cls
```

which when run results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dev/python/scratch/subclass_exception.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise HTTPExceptions.subclasses['Error501']
__main__.Error501
```